# How to avoid a circular #include involving a global variable?

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files

I have a header `myglobal.h` that declares two global objects:

```
#include "log.h"  // defines Clog
Clog log_file;

#include "lib.h"
Clib main_lib;
```

However, my `lib.h` also uses the global header:

```
#include "myglobal.h"  // error: circular #include

class Clib
{
  void func(void) { log_file << "hello"; }
}
```

How do I write these headers to avoid the `#include` loop?

Comment: Define a method to access this global object, cough... cough... singleton, cough..., instead.

Comment: I removed the trivial header, separated the important two, and fixed the title (and some spelling and formatting) to make your question clearer and easier to read.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add `extern` in the header file,

```
// myglobal.h
#include "log.h"
extern Clog log_file;

// #include "lib.h"  DO NOT include this one
extern Clib main_lib;
```

then define it in the cpp file (log.cpp)

```
 #include "log.h"
 Clog log_file;
```

and `move` the definition of clib also to a cpp file (lib.cpp, for example).

```
 #include "myglobal.h"

 void Clib::func(void) { log_file << "hello"; }
```

If you cannot move the definition out of the header file, you just need a cpp file to define the `Clib main_lib`. Other than that, it should be fine as long as you have include guard for all your headers.

Comment: That's good advice, but it doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What if they want `Clib::func` to be inline, or it's a template?

Answer (score 0):

The root problem of your circular #include is circular thinking. In particular, the idea of a global header both defines and depends on your library.

You solve this by *not* depending on `myglobal.h` in the implementation of your library. One simple way would be to move `CLib::func` to `lib.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated in CS Pei's answer, note that you need include guards, and that variable declarations in header files need `extern` (and a separate definition in a source file).  In C++17, you can [use `inline` instead](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) and let the linker sort it out.

Meanwhile, there are a few strategies to choose from based on your use case.

## Forward-declare `Clib`

Have `myglobal.h` merely declare `Clib`, not define it:

```
#include "log.h"
extern Clog log_file;

class Clib;
extern Clib main_lib;
```

Then it can be `#include`d by `lib.h` without issue.  However, clients which `#include"myglobal.h"` alone will not be able to *use* `main_lib`, since its type is incomplete.

## Put `log_file` in its own header

Since `Clib` depends not only on `Clog` but `log_file`, it is plainly at a higher level of interface.  Formalize this by creating `globallog.h`:

```
#include "log.h"
extern Clog log_file;
```

Then `lib.h` can include that without circularity:

```
#include "globallog.h"

class Clib
{
  void func(void) { log_file << "hello"; }
}
```

Finally, `myglobal.h` includes that and adds `main_lib`:

```
#include "globallog.h"  // optional: clarifies that log_file is made available
#include "lib.h"
extern Clib main_lib;
```

## Declare global objects with their classes

### Declare `main_lib` in `lib.h`

If no file wants `lib.h` without (your current) `myglobal.h` (perhaps because the only `Clib` used is `main_lib`), you can just move the declaration of `main_lib` into `lib.h`:

```
#include "myglobal.h"  // only log_file now

class Clib
{
  void func(void) { log_file << "hello"; }
}

extern Clib main_lib;
```

Note that this is a variation of the previous "`log_file` in its own header" strategy where `log_file` is instead the only thing *left* in the existing header.

### Declare `log_file` in `log.h`

Symmetrically, if no file wants `log.h` without using `log_file`, declare it there and leave `myglobal.h` with just `main_lib`:

```
#include "lib.h"
extern Clib main_lib;
```

Then `lib.h` is just

```
#include "log.h"

class Clib
{
  void func(void) { log_file << "hello"; }
}
```